# Как закрепить Scrollbar справа на главном окне, если внутри все упаковано с помощью .grid()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.6

Не могу понять как сделать, чтоб скроллбар прижать к правой стороне главного окна, так, чтоб было можно его использовать. Сам скроллбар находится в главном окне (root), а все остальное находится во frame  и упаковано с помощью .grid()

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("450x450+100+50")
root.resizable(width=tk.FALSE, height=tk.FALSE)

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient = 'vertical')
scrollbar.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: добавьте *минимальный* пример кода, который проблему демонстрирует (что со scrollbar происходит) [mcve]

Comment: @jfs вот, добавил. Понятия не имею, как его "прилепить" к правой стороне. Правда, у меня там еще много всяких виджетов, но происходит все то же самое, он по центру и внизу

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью упаковщика `place()`. Вместо `scrollbar.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT)` пишите `scrollbar.place` (x=количество пикселей по ширине, y=количество пикселей по высоте).

Если получите ошибку, попробуйте перед x и перед y написать `tk`.